# npm found 1high severity vulnerability

Tags: laravel, npm

I'm quite new to this. When installing the laravel echo package I get the following error, but as far as I can see I have installed the package correctly.

How can I fix this error?

```
 npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN ws@7.4.2 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN ws@7.4.2 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: the package you are trying to install is not compatible with the current environment.

Comment: Is there no solution?

Comment: you have to specify the compatible version of the echo package while install.

Comment: But in reality the system is working properly. Can it be left like this?

Comment: well, it is a warning only. you can skip if the things are working.